# ASP.net/Database Make Real time Balance

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database, visual-studio

So i am trying to create a small Budget management system with ASP.net but i don't know how to approach one part of this.. So any help would be appreciated...

So what i am trying to do is to make a simple budget management system which can do the following things:

- A Work Table: stores the works the company has taken done.
- An Income Table: stores how much income has come from the works (Link using Foreign Keys to Work Table)
- An Expense Table: stores on all kind of expenses (Link using Foreign Key to Work Table if necessary)
- A Balance Table: Store, the cash on hand which needs to increase if income comes, and decrease if any expense has occurred.

I need to make the real time/Current Balance to be visible.

So wat i dont know is how to approach the balance table? Should i make a new record to be created each time an income or expense is added?

If possible can anyone explain how to approach this balance thing? also wat kind of coding or formula is required here?

Comment: you can simply make one ledger table and show the current balance in the last inserted row

Comment: Can you please explain a little  more? I am a noob... Sorry about it...